# Putting User Selected Attachments into mysql DB

Tags: php, forms, attachment

I currently have a form where customer service reps can insert call logs.  I want to have something that allows a user to select a file that upon form submit will be uploaded to my database. Can anyone provide an example or a resource that might lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Uploading files using POST

I'm assuming that you want to store the file on the server and not actually put it into the database (large numbers of files inserted in your database as BLOBs will be incredibly bad for performance).

**Front-End**

In short, create an upload field in your form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    Send this file: <input name="call-log" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Log" />
</form>
```

**Storing The File**

Then handle the upload:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['call-log']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['call-log']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

**Remembering The Location**

Then put the file location in your database table (examples using `mysqli` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)) because `mysql` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) attracts nerd-rage):

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['call-log']['name']);
$mysqli   = new mysqli('localhost','some_user','some_password','database');
$stmt     = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (file-location) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $filename);
$stmt->execute;
```

Examples ad-hoced from PHP documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can check following html form input

```
<input type="file">
```